# How to get data set in j2me application?

Tags: java, web-services, java-me

I am using web service built in .net in which I want to return data as data set. I am able to send data in a data set, but don't know how to get it java j2me application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no class available for that in j2me. By the way you can return the data as XML format. You can parse the XML and get the values. I seen this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for writing DataSet as XML format. But I don't have knowledge in .net, So you have to create with own stuff. ;)